# problem with user defaults when saving a game... (int array)

Tags: iphone, arrays, save, nsuserdefaults

i have a problem with saving something and am officially out of ideas.
what i want to do is save an integer array into the userDefaults, then when restarting the app loading this array and restart the game from this last point.

what i do is that after each turn my AI logic saves the actual game state into an array -> so far so good this works fine. the array is saved and when i "re"read the saved array it seems ok... well actually it has saved the correct array!

now i restart the game. i check for a bool variable that i also saved if the game was interrupted out of the orderly. works fine too.

now the trick part. i read the array from the userDefaults and WOHOOO! i get a slighty different array then i saved! i really really cant figure out why :(

well: now the code:

here is what i do to save the board:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&boardToSave length:sizeof(boardToSave)];
[userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"MB_boardSave"];
```

and here what i do to get the data back when initialising the board:

```
int loadBoard[8][8] = {0};
NSData *data = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"MB_boardSave"];
memcpy(&loadBoard, data.bytes, data.length);
```

again... whats going in is correct, whats coming out is not :(

any suggestions would be very much appreciated!
i´m also open to alternative saving options if you think there are better ones!

thx

Comment: besides any solutions, would you please share what *is* going in and coming out?

Comment: for example: the first 8 array entries i save: 12, 2, 12, 0, 12, 2, 12, 2 ---- and the first 8 that are loaded: 12, 2, 12, 21, 12, 2, 12, 2 ---- only difference is 21 instead of 0... but that changes a lot on the board ;)

the

Comment: I updated my answer because I missed the *very obvious* bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit** the bug is that you `memcpy` to `&loadBoard`. It should be plain `loadBoard`, since that is a pointer. Same goes for `boardToSave`.

The funny thing is that it does kind of work (and not crash) as you do it.

Comment: i didnt but it doenst work anyhow :( sizeof() and .length do return the same value (see below)

Comment: oh and boardToSave is indeed defined int boardToSave[8][8]

Comment: :) it does not crash either way but even that eay of writing it produces the same thing... right ones go in wrong ones come out :(

Comment: so you removed two `&` and *nothing* changed. Now *that* is really odd.

Comment: your answer is certainly correct, but please see mine and have a good laugh :)

Answer (score 0):

im terribly  sorry but its code blindness struck me :)

where i wanted this

```
if(loadBoard[j][i] == 1 || loadBoard[j][i] == 11 || loadBoard[j][i] == 12){
 [...];
}
```

i had this

```
if(loadBoard[j][i] == 1 || boardSetup[j][i] == 11 || boardSetup[j][i] == 12){
 [...];
}
```

no wonder it didnt work :)
BUT for all that its worth there was some knid of mistake with saving and loading the array as well after i had the right results i was able to find the above "eye"bug :)

what i did now to save the array is to not use an int[8][8] array but an NSMutableArray that i save directly into the userDefaults. (no more memcopy and so on...)
here is what i did and what (finally) works for me

save:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// ... fill Array like so: [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:11]]; ...
[userDefaults setObject:array forKey:@"MB_boardSave"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

load:

```
NSArray* array = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"MB_boardSave"];
int example = [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

maybe thats usefull for someone else as well!

Comment: btw do you `release` the array? I suggest an `autorelease` after the `init`.

Comment: i did release it but changed to autorelease. thx for the hint!